# AutoComplete Google Places get error :This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

i'm trying to develop Maps with autocomplete textview with Google API.

i tried this tutorial [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/selecting-google-place-from-autocompletetextview-and-marking-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)

but i always get this error when i'm tryin to get the API :

```
{
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

i tried to find the solution, and i tried all the solution, like to use a **browser key**, **server key**, **enable the google places & map**, **delete & recreate project**, but i still get the error here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    AutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces;

    DownloadTask placesDownloadTask;
    DownloadTask placeDetailsDownloadTask;
    ParserTask placesParserTask;
    ParserTask placeDetailsParserTask;

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    final int PLACES=0;
    final int PLACES_DETAILS=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView
        atvPlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
        atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);

        // Adding textchange listener
        atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Creating a DownloadTask to download Google Places matching "s"
                placesDownloadTask = new DownloadTask(PLACES);

                // Getting url to the Google Places Autocomplete api
                String url = getAutoCompleteUrl(s.toString());

                // Start downloading Google Places
                // This causes to execute doInBackground() of DownloadTask class
                placesDownloadTask.execute(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        atvPlaces.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                atvPlaces.showDropDown();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Setting an item click listener for the AutoCompleteTextView dropdown list
        atvPlaces.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index,
                                    long id) {

                ListView lv = (ListView) arg0;
                SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) arg0.getAdapter();

                HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(index);

                // Creating a DownloadTask to download Places details of the selected place
                placeDetailsDownloadTask = new DownloadTask(PLACES_DETAILS);

                // Getting url to the Google Places details api
                String url = getPlaceDetailsUrl(hm.get("reference"));

                // Start downloading Google Place Details
                // This causes to execute doInBackground() of DownloadTask class
                placeDetailsDownloadTask.execute(url);

            }
        });
    }

    private String getAutoCompleteUrl(String place){

        // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "key=<INSERT API KEY HERE>";

        // place to be be searched
        String input = "input="+place;

        // place type to be searched
        String types = "types=geocode";

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }

    private String getPlaceDetailsUrl(String ref){

        // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "key=<INSERT API KEY HERE>";

        // reference of place
        String reference = "reference="+ref;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = reference+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        private int downloadType=0;

        // Constructor
        public DownloadTask(int type){
            this.downloadType = type;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            switch(downloadType){
                case PLACES:
                    // Creating ParserTask for parsing Google Places
                    placesParserTask = new ParserTask(PLACES);

                    // Start parsing google places json data
                    // This causes to execute doInBackground() of ParserTask class
                    placesParserTask.execute(result);

                    break;

                case PLACES_DETAILS :
                    // Creating ParserTask for parsing Google Places
                    placeDetailsParserTask = new ParserTask(PLACES_DETAILS);

                    // Starting Parsing the JSON string
                    // This causes to execute doInBackground() of ParserTask class
                    placeDetailsParserTask.execute(result);
            }
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        int parserType = 0;

        public ParserTask(int type){
            this.parserType = type;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<HashMap<String, String>> list = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                switch(parserType){
                    case PLACES :
                        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();
                        // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                        list = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                        break;
                    case PLACES_DETAILS :
                        PlaceDetailsJSONParser placeDetailsJsonParser = new PlaceDetailsJSONParser();
                        // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                        list = placeDetailsJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return list;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            switch(parserType){
                case PLACES :
                    String[] from = new String[] { "description"};
                    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

                    // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView
                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);

                    // Setting the adapter
                    atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;
                case PLACES_DETAILS :
                    HashMap<String, String> hm = result.get(0);

                    // Getting latitude from the parsed data
                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(hm.get("lat"));

                    // Getting longitude from the parsed data
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(hm.get("lng"));

                    // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of the activity_main.xml
                    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

                    // Getting GoogleMap from SupportMapFragment
                    googleMap = fm.getMap();

                    LatLng point = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                    CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point);
                    CameraUpdate cameraZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(5);

                    // Showing the user input location in the Google Map
                    googleMap.moveCamera(cameraPosition);
                    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraZoom);

                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                    options.position(point);
                    options.title("Position");
                    options.snippet("Latitude:"+latitude+",Longitude:"+longitude);

                    // Adding the marker in the Google Map
                    googleMap.addMarker(options);

                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me, any help will be appreciate thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using the Places API Web Service — you may find the Places API for Android suits you better as you're writing an Android app.  The Places API for Android will allow you to use an Android key, which can be restricted to be only usable by your app, unlike Server keys.

For using the Web Service follow the [Get a Key](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key) instructions in the Developer's Guide.  In particular make sure that you:

- Use a **Server key**, and
- Have enabled **Google Places API Web Service** (**not** the same as  Google Places API for Android) in the Google Developers Console.

Answer (score 0):

Go https://code.google.com/apis/console login with your id,
Create an application put all detail and generate API Key 
and put your API key in below code
// String key = "Put your API key here ";

```
private String getAutoCompleteUrl(String place){

        // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "Put your API key here "; here you update your key
    // 

        // place to be be searched
        String input = "input="+place;

        // place type to be searched
        String types = "types=geocode";

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }
```