# google_maps_browser_key returning error_message for autocomplete search

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-console

Here is a response that I'm getting. Note that I've created project in Firebase and Google API console. Added my SHA1 key in both the projects, generated the key. still not working. Also there is no restrictions in my API. 
I've already seen [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817785/autocomplete-google-places-get-error-this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use) and that didn't help
can anyone help ???

```
{
"error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",
"predictions" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" 
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the PlaceAPI on https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/.

Comment: wait for sometime.Nowadays it takes time to get activated

Comment: i've checked 100 times .. everything is enabled

Comment: I also faced same problem before few days ago. After tired i just delete the current project and created new one and passed new api key. It was working properly.
But do this thing only if your project is not published or not in use.

Comment: For me places api took about 1-2 hours to get activated